# Unit test using flexmock doesn't fail as expected

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to use *flexmock* with *test/unit* to create mock objects for my unit tests. This is my class under test:

```
class Cave
  def hunt
    # not yet implemented
  end
end
```

This is my unit test (note that this method is just one among many methods in the test case):

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'flexmock/test_unit'
require 'cave'

def test_play
  hunter = flexmock()

  cave = Cave.new
  cave.hunter = hunter

  hunter.should_receive(:turn).with(FlexMock.any).at_least.once

  cave.hunt
end
```

This test is supposed to verify that the `hunt` method sends the `turn` message to the object assigned to the `cave`'s `hunter` attribute at least once.

If I understand the documentation correctly, *flexmock* ties in with the unit testing framework and verifies the expectations defined in the tests automatically. Therefore, I expected the above test to fail, since the method `hunt` doesn't send `turn` yet. However, the test succeeds.

Am I missing something?

*Update*: I've set up a new file containing just one minimal test to see if flex mock would work at all as expected. The following test produces the expected result, i.e. fails:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'flexmock/test_unit'

class TestFoo < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_foo
    m=flexmock()
    m.should_receive(:bar).and_return(17).once
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that there is something wrong with your setup!

following the documentation and your example, i get the following output:

```
ruby test_foo.rb 
Run options: 

# Running tests:

[1/1] TestFoo#test_foo = 0.00 s
  1) Failure:
test_foo(TestFoo) [/Users/paule/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/flexmock-1.3.1/lib/flexmock/test_unit_integration.rb:53]:
in mock 'unknown': Method 'bar(*args)' called incorrect number of times
1 matching call expected
0 matching calls found
No messages have been received


Finished tests in 0.011163s, 89.5817 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
1 tests, 0 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

ruby -v: ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]
```

this indicates that everything runs fine using ruby 2.0.0p0.

Comment: I believe you're right - in another test case this works. I don't know what's the difference, but it's not worth the effort to find out since I'll be switching to rspec anyway. Thank you!

Comment: I switch from flexmock to [rr](https://github.com/rr/rr/) when flexmock [didn't run inside minitest](https://github.com/jimweirich/flexmock/issues/14).